# How to download a text file or some objects from webpage using Python?

Tags: python, json

I am writing a function that downloads and stores the today's list of pre-release domains .txt file from http://www.namejet.com/pages/downloads.aspx. I am trying to achieve it using json.

```
import json
import requests

def hello():
    r = requests.get('http://www.namejet.com/pages/downloads.aspx') 
    #Replace with your website URL

    with open("a.txt", "w") as f: 
    #Replace with your file name
        for item in r.json or []:
            try:
                f.write(item['name']['name'] + "\n") 
            except KeyError: 
                pass  

hello()
```

I need to download the file which consist of pre-release domains using python. How can I do that? Is the above code right way to do it?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with DNS resolution. I am assuming that the indentation is correct in your code, since its not right in your paste. Also, the link you are trying to open doesn't exist (404 error).

Comment: The link is: http://www.namejet.com/pages/downloads.aspx

Comment: Your error still has to do with DNS resolution. Once you get that resolved, `r.json` will be empty since the page doesn't return any json.

Answer (score 2):

I dont't think mechanize is much use for javascript, use [selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium). Here's an example:

```
In [1]: from selenium import webdriver
In [2]: browser=webdriver.Chrome() # Select browser that you want to automate 
In [3]: browser.get('http://www.namejet.com/pages/downloads.aspx')
In [4]: element=browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//a[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hlPreRelease1"]')

In [5]: element.click()
```

Now you can find `prerelease_10-08-2012.txt` in your download folder and you can open it in a usual way.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems with your approach:

1. The page doesn't return any json; so even if you were to access the page successfully, `r.json` will be empty:

   ```
   >>> import requests
   >>> r = requests.get('http://www.namejet.com/pages/downloads.aspx')
   >>> r.json
   ```
2. The file that you are after, is hidden behind a postback link; which you cannot "execute" using requests as it will not understand javascript.

In light of the above, the better approach is to use [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or alternatives to emulate a browser. You could also ask the company to provide you with a direct link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it won't download or get my any files. I want to download files under "Pre-Release Domains". Company won't provide me the direct link! So as today is 8th of October you want to get the file "Monday, October 08, 2012".