# How to download a file from a ASP website in Python?

Tags: python, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download a text file or some objects from webpage using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775250/how-to-download-a-text-file-or-some-objects-from-webpage-using-python)

I am trying to download a file under "Pre-Release Domains" from this website: `http://www.namejet.com/pages/downloads.aspx`
So as today is 10th of October you want to get the file "Wednesday, October 10, 2012".
When the click on the file the link doesn't changes so I have trouble writing python code to download the particular file as I don't have the specific URL of particular file. How do I write the script? I want everything to happen in the back end without actually opening the browser:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

browser=webdriver.Firefox() # Select browser that you want to automate 
browser.get('http://www.namejet.com/pages/downloads.aspx')
element=browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//a[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hlPreRelease1"]')
element.click()
display.stop()
```

This code runs without error but doesn't downloads the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: anchors on that page do not have urls to download. they point a javascript function which submits some other form and that form downloads the file. I you figure out how does that function work, you will be able to submit that form in python, hence download the files

Comment: you might want to ref-raze the question since `asp` is not really relevant. the question is more about web scraping.

Comment: It's your third question about the same problem and there have been at least two answers that solve it. Did you try selenium? I was able to download the file and i posted you the code?

Comment: I didn't got the code from you. Can you please paste the code as an answer in this question. I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: [@root's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12775585/4279).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: from selenium import webdriver
In [2]: browser=webdriver.Chrome() # Select browser that you want to automate 
In [3]: browser.get('http://www.namejet.com/pages/downloads.aspx')
In [4]: element=browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//a[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hlPreRelease1"]')

In [5]: element.click()
```

Now you can find prerelease_10-08-2012.txt in your download folder and you can open it in a usual way.

EDIT: note that the code downoads the latest file, that is prerelease_10-10-2012.txt as for today. Just tried it and it works fine.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks alot root!

Comment: Thanks, this script still requires me to actually manually approve the download in Firefox, it doesn't do it automatically and behind the scenes as is necessary. How do I do it? Thanks

Comment: The simpelest: use chrome, but you can also change firefox settings.

Comment: I want to integrate this in a big program and apply in real world. So, I want all this behind the scenes. Is there any way to modify this code as per my requirement?

Comment: what do you mean by "behind the scenes"? if you don't want to see the browser, use virtual display.

Comment: Yes, don't want to see the browser and download the file secretly? Can u please modify the code with virtual display?

Comment: just search the SO, all your questions have already been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924387/selenium-python-client-library-automating-in-background

Comment: hello root. I have updated my question with the code I have written. This code runs without error but doesn't download the file. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: did you change the settings of the browser? if not, it can't be working...The virtual display only hides the browser, doesn't change anything else.